# How to use PHPMailer (localhost+gmail) in a custom MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpmailer

I'm trying to send emails using the `PHPMailer` library and gmail in my MVC project. Here's what I did in my project. My project and files:

```
myproject
         -app
             -controllers
                        -AccountController.php
         -core
               -PHPMailer
                        -PHPMailer.php
                        -SMTP.php
                        -Exception.php
                        -MyCustomMailer.php
```

My `AccountController.php` has following code:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use Core\PHPMailer\MyCustomMailer;
...
class AccountController extends Controller {

...
public function sendSecurityCode(){
  $user_email = "example@gmail.com";
  $name = "John Doe";
  $code = "ranD0m"
  $mailer = new MyCustomMailer(true);
  $send = $mailer->sendSecurityCodeEmail($user_email, $name, $code);
  if($send) die("Sent.");
  else die("Not sent.");

}

}
```

And `MyCustomMailer.php` is somthing like this:

```
namespace Core\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once('PHPMailer.php');
require_once('SMTP.php');


class MyCustomMailer extends PHPMailer
{
    private $_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    private $_user = ''userJohnDoe@gmail.com';';
    private $_password = 'paSsW0rd';

    public function __construct($exceptions=true)
    {
        $this->isSMTP();
       
        $this->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $this->Host = $this->_host;
        $this->Port = 587;
        $this->Username = $this->_user;
        $this->Password = $this->_password;
        $this->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 

        parent::__construct($exceptions);
    }

    //   send security code email
    public function sendSecurityCodeEmail( $email, $name, $code){

        $mail_subject = "Security code account";
        $html_body = "";
        $mail_body = " Hey here is a test email and security code is: ". $code;
        $email_sent = self::sendEmail($email, $name, $mail_subject, $html_body, $mail_body);

        return $email_sent;
    }

   
    public static function sendEmail($to_email, $to_name, $subject, $html_body, $email_body){
        $mail_sent = false;
        try{
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->setFrom("noreply@example.com", "Example");
            $mail->addAddress($to_email,$to_name);
           
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            if(!empty($html_body)) {
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->AltBody = $email_body;
                $mail->Body    = $html_body;
            } else{
                $mail->Body    = $email_body;
            }

            if($mail->send()) $mail_sent = true;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }

        return $mail_sent;
    }
}
```

Getting errors `Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found`. What is right way to implement it in my MVC project??

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone having similar issues or looking for a MVC implementation: I made it work by adding the missing `Exception.php` in `MyCustomMailer.php`. Now it looks like this :

```
    ...
    require_once(__DIR__.'/PHPMailer.php');
    require_once(__DIR__.'/SMTP.php');
    require_once(__DIR__.'/Exception.php');

    ...
```

It solved the `PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found` problem. Then got another error `Could not connect to SMTP host` and solved it by updating the `sendEmail` function in `MyCustomMailer.php`. Here is the new `sendEmail` function:

```
public static function sendEmail($to_email, $to_name, $subject, $html_body, $email_body){
        $mail_sent = false;
        try{
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->setFrom("noreply@example.com", "Example");
            $mail->addAddress($to_email,$to_name);
           
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            if(!empty($html_body)) {
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->AltBody = $email_body;
                $mail->Body    = $html_body;
            } else{
                $mail->Body    = $email_body;
            }

        // added Gmail hack
         $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            if($mail->send()) $mail_sent = true;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }

        return $mail_sent;
    }
```

set the smtp `username` and `password` correctly and It's working just fine :) .

Comment: "Working just fine", apart from the bit where you suppress errors relating to your broken TLS config, leaving you open to man in the middle attacks. Please don't do that! Fix your server instead – there is plenty of documentation provided with PHP to show you how.

Comment: If you're really building projects worth dividing into MVC, the one vital piece of advice you should take is: **use composer**. Managing your own dependencies will get rapidly out of hand as soon as you start doing non-trivial things; you're already having trouble here and you're only using *one* library!

Comment: @Synchro `broken TLS config`/ `Fix your server` I'm afraid I didn't understand it clearly but I would love to learn. Can you explain or give me any good resource link. `use composer` thanks for the advice and I will.

Comment: Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for how to fix TLS. For composer go to getcomposer.com, and search.